# Opening new frame based on JComboBox selection

Tags: java, swing

I am a newbie to Java. I am doing a project on JavaSwing in college.

I want the functionality like when i select the item in the JComboBox it should display a new AlwaysOnTop frame with a label with Selected item name in that frame and when i select the another item then it should update only the label in the frame created earlier.

```
Here is my code:
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import Swing_Package.ToolbarFrame2;


public class JComboBoxExample extends JPanel{
        JComboBox cards;

        public JComboBoxExample(){
            String[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
            cards = new JComboBox(items);

            ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        cards = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
                        System.out.println(cards.getSelectedItem()+" ");
                    }
            };



            add(cards);
            cards.addActionListener(listener);
        }

        public static void createAndShowGUI(){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComboBox Demo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JComboBoxExample content = new JComboBoxExample();
            content.setOpaque(true);
            frame.setContentPane(content);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So instead of displaying the selected item on console it should it in new frame with respective selection.

Comment: Your post contains no '?'.  What is your *question?*

Comment: When I select the item from JComboBox, it should pop-up new frame with a message or JLabel of selected item. Lets say i have 3 items(Item 1, Item 2, Item 3) in combobox, when i select "Item 1" it should pop-up new frame which will display "U have Selected: Item 1".

Comment: The only question marks in this post are the 2 I wrote - so you **still** have not asked a question.  It ain't rocket science.

Comment: Hi Andrew, with all do respect i am new to this website, and i am still not sure what you are asking me to do, Just ignore me if your not interested in answering my above question

Answer (score 2):

1) it too hard to create `AlwaysOnTop frame` by using [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), you have to look for [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) with [ModalityType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29) or [setModal(Boolean)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29)

2) add [ItemListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) (always calls twice `SELECTED` and `DESELECTED` events) to the [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) instead of `ActionListener`

Comment: @rockwire: this is your solution: use a JDialog. (1+)